# Trying to find a working solution to setup Flutter with Firebase on Android. keep getting errors

Tags: firebase, flutter

I am trying to find the steps to get flutter working with Firebase with a clean Install of a flutter project and Firebase setup. Here is the bare minimum setup of files per their instructions.

my pubspec.yaml

```
  dev_dependencies:
   flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
 firebase_core: ^0.4.0+1
 firebase_auth: ^0.11.1+3
 cloud_firestore: ^0.12.9
```

my build.gradle file

```
     buildscript {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'
    }
}

allprojects {
  repositories {
     google()
     jcenter()
 }
}

 rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
 }
subprojects {
project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
} 

task clean(type: Delete) {
  delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and my /buildgradle file, I just added to this to end (per firestore instructions)

```
 apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I also put the `google.services.json` file into my android/app folder.

I then try to build and get this error:
FAILURE:

```
Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\Mike\Documents\VSCode Projects\flutterplayground\graceblox\android\app\build.gradle' line: 24

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> ASCII

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
  Command: C:\Users\Mike\Documents\VSCode Projects\flutterplayground\graceblox\android\gradlew.bat app:properties
```

Does anyone have the basic setup working ?? I have searched and found all kinds of responses to change the versions, add androidx, etc..but nothing seems to work. I'm hoping there is a defined set of oonfigurion steps someone has to get this working?

Comment: all firebase dependencies are using androidX and as so you have to migrate to androidX else run flutter clean then retry again

Comment: Thanks, I finally found the article that shows the changes necessary to make to get this to work here: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/androidx-compatibility .   Also, once I made these changes, I still got an error , but was resolve by adding this attribute multiDexEnabled set to true in app/build.gradle

Comment: That's interesting as in the debug console it shows an error clearly pointing to multidex .but great